# conditional redirection in bash

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, io-redirection

I have a bash script that I want to be quiet when run without attached tty (like from cron).
I now was looking for a way to conditionally redirect output to /dev/null in a single line.
This is an example of what I had in mind, but I will have many more commands that do output in the script

```
#!/bin/bash
# conditional-redirect.sh
if tty -s; then 
  REDIRECT=
else 
  REDIRECT=">& /dev/null"
fi
echo "is this visible?" $REDIRECT
```

Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
$ ./conditional-redirect.sh
is this visible?
$ echo "" | ./conditional-redirect.sh 
is this visible? >& /dev/null
```

what I don't want to do is duplicate all commands in a with-redirection or with-no-redirection variant:

```
if tty -s; then 
  echo "is this visible?"
else 
  echo "is this visible?" >& /dev/null
fi
```

**EDIT:**

It would be great if the solution would provide me a way to output something in "quiet" mode, e.g. when something is really wrong, I might want to get a notice from cron.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For `bash`, you can use the line:

```
exec &>/dev/null
```

This will direct *all* `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null` from that point on. It uses the non-argument version of `exec`.

Normally, something like `exec xyzzy` would replace the program in the current process with a new program but you can use this non-argument version to simply modify redirections while keeping the current program.

So, in your specific case, you could use something like:

```
tty -s
if [[ $? -eq 1 ]] ; then
    exec &>/dev/null
fi
```

If you want the majority of output to be discarded but still want to output some stuff, you can create a new file handle to do that. Something like:

```
tty -s
if [[ $? -eq 1 ]] ; then
  exec 3>&1 &>/dev/null
else 
  exec 3>&1
fi
echo Normal               # won't see this.
echo Failure >&3          # will see this.
```

Comment: ..but it has the downside that all output is lost in "quiet" mode; there might be situations where I actually want to output something, even in queit mode; see upodated question.

Comment: Good point, @daniel, I'm getting a bit long in the tooth and old habits die hard but I've updated answer using your preferred way.

Comment: Aahh, I can redirect to `/dev/tty` in that case!

Comment: I think I have to use `[[ $? -eq 1 ]]`

Comment: once i do  
    "exec &>/dev/null"  
how do i best revert back to initial "pre-redirect" exec redirection settings?

Comment: @theartofrain: you ask _another question on SO._ That way, everyone sees it rather than just me, and you have more chance of getting a good range of answers. FWIW, you can store the current handles: `exec 8>&1 9>&2 &>/dev/null` and then later do `exec 1>&8 2>&9` to restore.

Answer (score 12):

I found another solution, but I feel it is clumsy, compared to paxdiablo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8756552/85615):

```
if tty -s; then 
  REDIRECT=/dev/tty
else 
  REDIRECT=/dev/null
fi
echo "Normal output" &> $REDIRECT
```

Comment: That will work but only if the output isn't redirected. `/dev/tty` always refers to your terminal device so, if you've run your script with `myscript >xyzzy.log`, the output you send to `/dev/tty` won't end up in that log file. That may not matter though it depends on how you want to use your program.

Comment: @paxdiablo you can use `/dev/stdout` instead of `/dev/tty` to work around this

Answer (score 5):

You can use a function:

```
function the_code {
    echo "is this visible?"
    # as many code lines as you want
}

if tty -s; then # or other condition
  the_code
else 
  the_code >& /dev/null
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me. If `DUMP_FILE` is empty things go to stdout otherwise to the file. It does the job without using explicit redirection, but just uses pipes and existing applications.

```
function stdout_or_file
{
    local DUMP_FILE=${1:-}

    if [ -z "${DUMP_FILE}" ]; then
        cat
    else
        sed -n "w ${DUMP_FILE}"
    fi
}

function foo()
{
    local MSG=$1
    echo "info: ${MSG}"
}

foo "bar" | stdout_or_file ${DUMP_FILE}
```

Of course, you can squeeze this also in one line

```
foo "bar" | if [ -z "${DUMP_FILE}" ]; then cat; else sed -n "w ${DUMP_FILE}"; fi
```

Besides `sed -n "w ${DUMP_FILE}"` another command that does the same is `dd status=none of=${DUMP_FILE}`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use eval (a shell builtin), as it will act on the redirection in the expanded variable... and also act on anything else in the command line, so add extra quoting as required (note the extra single quotes added around the echo string below due to the '?' which would otherwise cause shell filename expansion to be attempted).

```
#!/bin/bash
# conditional-redirect.sh
if tty -s; then 
  REDIRECT=
else 
  REDIRECT=">& /dev/null"
fi
eval echo '"is this visible?"' $REDIRECT
```